# Passing of data(including image) from ListView to another activity (independent of each ListView options) and initialise starting values for each

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having an issue to pass data from ListView to the BuyerHome activity. Data in ListView includes Item Name, Description, Starting Price, Duration and Image. Item Name and Description are done without errors. However, the Starting price, duration, and image, I could not get it right, as it conflicts with the other codes that I have that will update the values of them(for the duration and starting price). For image-wise, I am not too sure which format in order for me to pass the image over.

And also, whenever click on each ListView option, they should be independent of each other. As now my app duplicates the values to all my activities when clicked.

AuctionList.java:

```
public class AuctionList extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView mListView;

ArrayList<Model> mList = new ArrayList<>();;
AuctionListAdapter mAdapter = null;
DatabaseHelperUpload mDBUpload;


TextView txtName,txtDescription,txtDuration,txtPrice;
ImageView imageViewIcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.auction_list);
    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);



    mDBUpload = new DatabaseHelperUpload(this);
    mListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    mAdapter = new AuctionListAdapter(this,R.layout.row,mList);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    txtName = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtDescription = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    txtDuration = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
    txtPrice = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);



    final Cursor cursor = mDBUpload.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD");
    mList.clear();
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String description = cursor.getString(2);
        String price = cursor.getString(3);
        String duration = cursor.getString(4);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(5);

        mList.add(new Model(id,name,description,price,duration,image));
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(mList.size() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Auctions Currently", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Model e = mList.get(position);

            String name = e.getName();
            String description = e.getDescription();
            String price = e.getPrice();
            String duration = e.getDuration();
            //byte[] image = e.getImage();
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(AuctionList.this,BuyerHome.class);
            intent5.putExtra("name",name);
            intent5.putExtra("description",description);
            intent5.putExtra("price",price);
            intent5.putExtra("duration",duration);
            //intent5.putExtra("image",image);

            startActivity(intent5);
        }
    });


}
```

BuyerHome.java:

```
public class BuyerHome extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
EditText nameIn;
EditText commentIn;
TextView viewComment;
TextView textPrice;
Button postComment;
ListView olderComments;
private DrawerLayout drawer; //Drawer
private int currentPrice;
private static long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS ;



DatabaseHelper2 myDB;
Cursor oldermessages, latestmessage;
Cursor latestprice;
SimpleCursorAdapter sma;

DatabaseHelper4 myDB2;





private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
private Button mButtonStart;




private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

private boolean mTimerRunning;

private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
private long mEndTime;

private TextView TextViewPrice;
private Button newPrice;

DatabaseHelperUpload mDBUpload;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buyer_home);

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Addon,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);







    newPrice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_bid);

    mDBUpload = new DatabaseHelperUpload(this);


    nameIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    commentIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentText);
    viewComment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewCommentText);
    olderComments = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.olderComments); //<<<<<<<<<< Added
    textPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
    TextViewPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_newprice);


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //Drawer
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //Drawer

    mTextViewCountDown = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    mButtonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();



    String name = bundle.getString("name");
    String duration = bundle.getString("duration");
    String price = bundle.getString("price");





    TextView durationLog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
    TextView priceLog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPrice);
    TextView nameLog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
    //TextView pricelog2 = findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);


    durationLog.setText(duration);
    priceLog.setText(price);
    nameLog.setText(name);
    //pricelog2.setText(price);




    myDB2 = new DatabaseHelper4(this);
    newPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String price = textPrice.getText().toString();

            if (nameIn.length() != 0) {
                    String name = nameIn.getText().toString();

                    myDB2.addPrice(name, price);
                    nameIn.setEnabled(false);

                    displayPrice();
                    displayPrice2();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(BuyerHome.this, "Please Insert Username To Bid.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState(); //Drawer
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    myDB = new DatabaseHelper2(this);
    postComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonComment);
    postComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = nameIn.getText().toString();
            String comment = commentIn.getText().toString();

            if (nameIn.length() != 0 && commentIn.length() != 0) {
                myDB.addData(name, comment); //<<<<<<<<<< method starts changed lower case a
                nameIn.setEnabled(false);
                commentIn.setText("");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(BuyerHome.this, "Insert fields",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            displayComments(); //<<<<<<<<<< added to refresh the display according to the latest comments
        }
    });



    mButtonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startTimer();
        }
    });


}

private static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

@Override //Drawer
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

//<<<<<<<<<< ADDED so will display comments whenever called including returning from another activity
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    displayComments();
    displayPrice();
    displayPrice2();

}

private void displayPrice2() {

    latestprice = myDB2.getLatestPrice();
    if (latestprice.moveToFirst()) {

        String a = String.valueOf(latestprice.getString(latestprice.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper4.COL_BID_PRICE)));
        currentPrice = Integer.parseInt(a);

    } else {
        TextViewPrice.setText("");
    }
}

private void displayPrice() {
    latestprice = myDB2.getLatestPrice();
    if (latestprice.moveToFirst()) {
        TextViewPrice.setText( latestprice.getString(latestprice.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper4.COL_BID_NAME))+
                " Bids $" + latestprice.getString(latestprice.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper4.COL_BID_PRICE)));
    } else {
        TextViewPrice.setText("");
    }
}

//<<<<<<<<<< ADDED entire method for displaying comments
private void displayComments() {
    latestmessage = myDB.getLatestComment();

    if (latestmessage.moveToFirst()) {
        viewComment.setText(
                latestmessage.getString(latestmessage.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper2.COL_COMMENT_NAME)) +
                        " said : " +
                        latestmessage.getString(latestmessage.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper2.COL_COMMENT_COMMENT)));
    } else {
        viewComment.setText("");
    }
    oldermessages = myDB.getAllButLatestComment();
    if (sma == null) {
        sma = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,oldermessages,
                new String[]{DatabaseHelper2.COL_COMMENT_NAME,DatabaseHelper2.COL_COMMENT_COMMENT},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
                0
        );
        olderComments.setAdapter(sma);
    } else {
        sma.swapCursor(oldermessages);
    }
}

public void startTimer(){
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setEnabled(false);//upon finish,stop the function to bid and wait for seller to delete post.
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
}

private void resetTimer() {
    //START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 600000;
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateTimer();
    mButtonStart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void updateTimer(){
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis/1000)/60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis/1000) %60;

    String timeLeftFormat = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds);

    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormat);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String text = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

    int numberInSpinner = Integer.parseInt(text);

    int sum = numberInSpinner + currentPrice;
    textPrice.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_inst:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Instructions.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_auctionlist:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AuctionList.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_sell:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SellerHome.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_logout:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AucOn.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_email:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerSupport.class));
            break;

    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putLong("millisLeft",mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning",mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime",mEndTime);

    editor.apply();

    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning",false);

    updateTimer();

    if(mTimerRunning){
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();


        if (mTimeLeftInMillis<0){
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateTimer();

        } else{
            startTimer();

        }
    }
}
}
```

I believe it might have to do with the SQLite Database as well, so here you go:

```
public class DatabaseHelperUpload extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



private final static String DBNAME = "Auction";
private final static int DBVERSION = 2;

DatabaseHelperUpload(Context context){
    super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}

public void queryData(String sql){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL(sql);
}

public void insertData(String name, String description, String price, String duration, byte[] image){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?)";

    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString(1,name);
    statement.bindString(2,description);
    statement.bindString(3,price);
    statement.bindString(4,duration);
    statement.bindBlob(5,image);

    statement.executeInsert();

}


public Cursor getData(String sql){
    SQLiteDatabase database=getReadableDatabase();

    return database.rawQuery(sql,null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: use this one instance of a bundle

        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String duration = getIntent().getExtras().getString("duration");
        String price = getIntent().getExtras().getString("price");

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get data from the bundle in **BuyerHome** activity then you should put data into bundle from **AuctionList** activity.

put all data that you want to pass in **BuyerHome** activity into a bundle and then pass it.

**AuctionList.class:**

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Model e = mList.get(position);

            String name = e.getName();
            String description = e.getDescription();
            String price = e.getPrice();
            String duration = e.getDuration();
            //byte[] image = e.getImage();
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(AuctionList.this, BuyerHome.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", name);
            bundle.putString("description", description);
            bundle.putString("price", price);
            bundle.putString("duration", duration);
            //intent5.putExtra("image",image);
            intent5.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(intent5);
        }
    });
```

Thank You.